# Почему прилагательное ПОСЛЕДНИЙ можно классифицировать как относительное?

Tags: семантика, прилагательные

Помогите разобраться в следующем вопросе:

> Почему прилагательное **последний** можно классифицировать как относительное?

*Прим.* Имеется в виду употребление в прямом смысле, где нет перехода в качественность.

Comment: Послушайте, если "нет перехода в качественность", то каким еще может быть прилагательное, если не относительным?

Comment: @behemothus Имеется в виду, что гипотетически можно сконструировать контекст, где исходное прилагательное приобретёт признаки качественности. Такие случаи не являются предметом интереса настоящего вопроса.

Comment: Да конструируйте себе на здоровье. Вы бы лучше свой игнтерес направили на учебник класса этак шестого. Где рассказано о разрядах прилагательных.

Answer (score 2):

Если пользоваться *развёрнутым* определением относительного прилагательного (см. напр. http://russkiyyazik.ru/609/ ), то можно заметить, что в это понятие входят прилагательные, обозначающие признак предмета не обязательно через "другой предмет" (иногда определение упрощают до этого свойства), а и такие, которые делают это через "*действие*", "*место*" или "*время*". В нашем случае это обозначение происходит через **место** обозначаемого предмета относительно прочих аналогичных предметов (последний кирпич в ряду кладки).

Comment: А вам не кажется, что вы в открытую дверь ломитесь? Зачем все эти вещи, если у прилагательного нет качественного значения (что признает автор) и оно явно не является притяжательным. Чего огород-то городить с какими-то "развернутыми определениями"?!

Answer (score 2):

Полностью согласна с Александром. Можно дополнить.

Если нужно доказательство, то следует сказать, что прилагательное последний полностью соответствует ВСЕМ признакам этой категории.

**Оно обозначает признак предмета опосредованно**.

Относительные прилагательные обозначают признак через отношение к другому предмету, действию или обстоятельству .
**Последний - тот, который стоит после всех.** через **обстоятельство после всех**.

Если вспомнить его этимологию, форма последний — производное от др.-русск., ст.-слав., сербск.-церк.-слав. послѣдь (у нас сейчас есть сущ. **послед**). От него образовалось др.-русск. послѣди, (как **по завершении)** - потом, впоследствии.

Грамматические признаки:

1. Наличие полной склоняемой формы и отсутствие краткой.
2. Является производным словом, образуется от наречия после, исторически от сущ. послед (послѣдь), ещё раньше от сущ. след.
3. Как все относительные прилагательные, обозначает постоянный, неизменяемый признак.
4. Можно заменить синонимичной падежной формой, только не существительного, а сочетанием с существительным (последняя книга- книга после книг).

https://studopedia.su/15_177147_otnositelnie-prilagatelnie.html

Можно и методом от противного: Это не притяжательное (нельзя задать вопрос чей?), но и не качественное (нельзя образовать степени сравнения,  краткую форму,придумать сочетание с наречием **очень**)

Answer (score 0):

Значит так. 
Прилагаетльные бывают качественными, относительными и притяжательными.
Если у прилагательного нет "качественного значения" (по вашему выражению), то оно или относительное или притяжательное. Притяжательным оно не является.

Что еще надо, чтобы ответить на вопрос "почему?".

//===

*Всегда говорил, что вопросы, начинающиеся с "почему?" на этом ресурсе надо сразу закрывать. Они или банальны, или абсурдны по своей сути.*

//==========
Продолжаю комментировать комментарии.

> хочет выяснить, каким образом слово укладывается в учебные определения

А что тут непонятного-то? В школе даются разряды прилагательных. Качественные, относительные, прилагательные. Куда ж прилагательному бедному укладываться, если качественное значение из рассмотрения исключено, а притяжательным оно заведомо не является?
И это по **любому** определению (ну если только оно не посягает на само представление о трех разрядах прилагательных). Чего огород-то городить?

Я уж не говорю, что из постановки вопроса совсем не следует, что автор что-то там хочет выяснить. Он вообще ставит вопрос "Почему?". Вот вынь да положь причинно-сле6дственную связь.

Comment: Как и автор вопроса, я допускаю контексты, когда это прилагательное можно "заподозрить" в выражении качественных признаков, например, когда оно имеет значение "законченный/полнейший" (лох, негодяй и т. п.). Он такие контексты исключил из рассмотрения и интересуется, как именно подвести слово под сложившуюся классификацию.

Comment: @Alex_ander  мне кажется я попал в какой-то театр абсурда. 1. Какое отношение к моему тексту имеют ваши допущения? 2. Коли вам так важно рассуждать на тему контекста, то объясните, как ваше допущение согласуется с его текстом? Он же явно пишет, что **не имеет в виду значение**, которое можно в этом заподозрить?! Или я что-то не понимаю в этой логике?

Comment: В этом тексте вы высказали предположение, что автор вопроса в принципе отрицает "качественные значения" у этого прилагательного. Но он лишь исключил этот специфический случай из рассмотрения и хочет выяснить, _каким образом_ слово укладывается в учебные определения. В разных источниках они весьма путаные - либо неполные (в классификации по смыслу), либо они зачем-то ориентируют на поиск суффиксов, один из которых непременно должен найтись в качественном прилагательном, и т. п. Классификация методом исключения автору вопроса не интересна, ему нужен, _метод_, приводящий к известному ему ответу.

Comment: @Alex_ander *в принципе отрицает "качественные значения" у этого прилагательного* - простите, я ничего подобного не делал. Могу только попросить еще раз перечитать выделенное болдом в моем предыдущем комментарии. Вот ровно это я сказал в своем ответе. Он **не рассматривает** такие значения, а не говорит, что их нет вообще. Ровно это делаю и я. Качественные значения не рассматриваю. Остальное - в тексте ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Почему прилагательное *последний* можно классифицировать как относительное?

Прим. Имеется в виду употребление в прямом смысле, где нет перехода в качественность.

**Вопрос, действительно, кажется странным.** Если его понимать в прямом смысле, то ответ очевиден: а как прилагательное ***последний*** еще классифицировать? Оно не качественное и  не притяжательное? Ну тогда очевидно, что оно относительное.

**Другой ответ также очевиден: по определению.** Относительное прилагательное выражает признак не прямо, а через отношение к чему-либо.

В этом плане прилагательное ***последний*** **просто образец для всех других относительных прилагательных,** так как определяет признак **через место в ряду однородных предметов,** а это совсем не постоянный и отнюдь не существенный признак: начнем считать с другой стороны, и последний станет первым.

**И грамматических показателей** качественного прилагательного  у него нет (степени сравнения, краткой формы и т.д.). Так что же еще нужно, **все формальности соблюдены в полной мере.**

**Дополнительный комментарий к ответу**

Формальности — да, а вот философия вопроса не очень ясна. Деление прилагательных на качественные и относительные — это вещь весьма  условная.  **Качество** определяется как существенный признак, свойство, отличающее один предмет  от другого. **Так в чем выражается существенность качественного признака?**

**Это постоянный признак?** Ничуть, ведь, к примеру, *деревянный и каменный* дом — это признаки  постоянные и названные предметы между собой очень даже различны, а прилагательные считаются **относительными**.

**Или качественное прилагательное должно быть  непроизводным?** Тоже нет. *Сильный, разговорчивый* — качественные прилагательные, но они производные.

Может быть, **грамматические свойства  должны быть обязательно соблюдены?** Нет, тоже не всегда: ведь нельзя сказать *очень красный, самый красный*.

**Так можно ли вообще однозначно обозначить качественный признак и, соответственно, признак относительный?**

**А переход относительного прилагательного в качественное** когда происходит, как его определить? По переносному  значению? Или, может, по однородным отношениям с другими качественными прилагательными?

И еще интересно: а **какой вообще практический смысл в делении прилагательных на качественные и относительные?** Это как-то способствует лучшему пониманию языка? Может быть, но вот в рамках школьного образования это деление, как и многие другие разборы, выглядит как довольно скучная формальность.